# Анимация стрелки скорости

Tags: ios, swift, анимация

Здравствуйте, пишу приложение "спидометр", скорость определять это одно, оказалось просто, а вот нарисовать стрелку спидометра как-то сложновато. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать подобное на swift? Ну или кто знает на objective-c, то посоветуйте тоже, разберусь потом, попробую под swift подогнать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или анимацию стрелка кто-нибудь подскажите, просто, чтобы она вращалась внутри.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сказал проще всего сделать `CGAffineTransform`. Вроде такого:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

arrow.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL); // точка центра вращения 0..1
arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RAD); //вращение в радианах
```

Comment: То есть закидывать в CGAffineTransform свою скорость, переводя ее в радианы? Спасибо, попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: У меня вроде получилось. Правда возникли некоторые трудности, особенно когда угол больше 180 градусов, но ничего пришлось сделать вложенную анимацию. Спасибо за совет. 
Остался только один вопрос по скрину, который в самом верху: Когда я установлю дизайн в программу, мне нужно будет ориентироваться по этому спидометру, чтобы совпадали значения стрелки. Мне нужно рисовать этот спидометр относительно тригонометрического круга? Или есть еще вариант как определять где 10км, а где 85км?

Comment: надо почитать вики :) насколько я помню 0км/ч будет примерно в 4rad и по мере увеличения скорости будет уменьшаться. там, где у вас 220км/ч будет примерно -1.5rad

Comment: Еще немного инфы: если смотреть по картинке, то от 40 до 200 ровно 3.14радиан. то есть соотношение будет 3.14/160. таким образом если эксперементально найти, где точка 0км/ч (это будет примерно 4.6 радиан) то потом на каждый 1км/ч уменьшать трансформацию на 3.14/160

Comment: Действительно полезная информация, спасибо) 
Остался последний вопрос, я создаю новое изображение для стрелки, но применяя arrow.layer.anchorPoint она у меня вся двигается, т.е. начало стрелки и конец. Я пробовал устанавливать значения (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0), но это не приносило особых улучшений. Что лучше, использовать квадратное изображение, или прямоугольное для того, чтобы один конец стрелки не двигался?

Comment: Вроде разобрался методом "клацанья") Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: насколько я помню, anchorPoint желательно ставить до добавления объекта во viewHierarchy (до вызова `addSubview`)